# Como fazer o keyframe parar no 100%/ficar estático após a animação?

Tags: html5, css3, div

Tenho o seguinte keyframe:

```
@keyframes bolha
    0%   {width: 0px;
         height: 0px;}
    50%  {width: 600px;
         height: 600px;}
    100% {width: 400px;
         height: 400px;}
}
```

chamo ele dessa forma:

```
-webkit-animation: bolha 1s;
```

O resultado: Execute 1 vez a animação e pare no 100% ficando estática.

Sou iniciante, desculpem pela ignorância...

Comment: Essa repetição só ocorre se você colocar `animation: bolha 1s infinite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adiciona o seguinte atributo no CSS: `animation-fill-mode: forwards`.

Pra funcionar em todos os navegadores:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Documentação [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)